# Failed to create object with Django ORM

Tags: python, django

Here is my code

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        SysPay.objects.bulk_create([
            SysPay(
                pay_way = '1',
                pay_account = request.POST.get('first_pay_account', ''),
                pay_appid = request.POST.get('first_pay_appid', ''),
                pay_key = request.POST.get('first_pay_key', ''),
            ),
            SysPay(
                pay_way = '2',
                pay_account = request.POST.get('second_pay_account', ''),
                pay_appid = request.POST.get('second_pay_appid', ''),
                pay_key = request.POST.get('second_pay_key', ''),
                pay_pid = request.POST.get('second_pay_pid', ''),
                ),
        ])
```

Here is my model

```
class SysPay(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
pay_way = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
pay_account = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
pay_appid = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
pay_key = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
pay_pid = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
stand_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
stand_rate_limit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
org_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
org_rate_limit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

first question:

It is so many "request.POST.get" here.Is't some way to make it more pythonic? I had try request.body,but I don't know how to selet the single value like that.

second question:

When I use SysPay.objects.create(...) to write data it works well.But when it comes to SysPay.objects.bulk_create([...]),it failed to write data together into the database.

Comment: This really should be two questions the first one probably belongs on the code review stack. FOr the second question you need to tell us if there is any error message.

Comment: @e4c5,For the second question,thers is no error message.That's also confuse me

Comment: Inspect the database log to see if there is anything. If not enable query logging in Django and see what query was sent to the database. See if that shows anything